# Two ubuntu server machines in one

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, solr, liferay

its my first post here so I hope im doing it in the right place.

Im setting up a DEV environment in Ubuntu, and being a software developer not really a sysadmin or application manager, I am confused in some steps.

At the moment I have the running servers of production, but they are two different machines, having two different IPs, lets say
Backend 192.10.1.1
Frontend 192.10.1.2

Now, i would not like to change the code and configuration, so to maintain the same structure as in PROD. That being said: I want to get everything in ONE Ubuntu server machine, with lets say IP 10.1.1.1.

Knowing that what I have:
Backend 
   - comprised of
      Liferay (tomcat server port 8080)
      Solr Master (port 8983) with Jetty
      Some custom made J2SE applications who communicate through webservices with liferay (calling on port 8080)

Frontend (lets say IP 192.168.1.2)
    - comprised of
       Solr Slave (port 8983) with Jetty
       HTML code+JS+CSS.. (apache 2 HTTP server)

I would know how to achieve this for different websites running on an apache2 http server...but since I have as well Solr and Liferay and Webservices, im confused.

Is there a way that my server 10.1.1.1 would be redirecting the calls to/from 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 to the correct application servers of backend and frontend in 10.1.1.1?

Maybe through some kind of proxy virtual network adapter?

Thank you a lot!!

Rui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One server can have multiple ip addresses. so you can have one server with both 192.10.1.1 and 192.10.1.2 (though you should probably use 192.168.10.1 and 192.168.10.2 unless you have those public ips). You can then run both the frontend and backed services on the same server but binding to the different ip addresses.

You can do this even if you have only one network interface.

Comment: After reading you i just googled "multiple ip addresses in one ubuntu server" and i got a bunch of results, I think i'll be able to make it work now. thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!!!

Comment: Hi, 

I solved the issue by setting up two different virtual network adapters in ubuntu server. 

case closed ;) 


thanks for the help!!